# Excel VBA - Range Value Function

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I am wanting to reference data from sheet 1 to a master sheet. The master sheet has macro embedded buttons to grab the information from different tab of sheets (sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3, etc.) to the master sheet.

Currently, I am using:
Worksheets("test sheet").Range("G2:H5").Value = Worksheets("products").Range("D2:E5").Value

This works fine but I have some snippets/images from other tabs that is not transferring over to the master sheet. This syntax is just transferring the values in the cells. Not the snippets or even the color of the cell if I have it highlighted in the original tab.

What do I need to adjust to ensure everything from the sheet gets referenced exactly the same?

Thank you!

Currently, I am using:
Worksheets("test sheet").Range("G2:H5").Value = Worksheets("products").Range("D2:E5").Value

I expect everything including the snippets (images using snip tool and copied pasted onto the tabs) and the color I highlighted to show on the master sheet when I click the buttons.

Comment: `.Value` does not include formatting or shapes. Sounds like you need to `.Copy`.

Comment: @BigBen, If I copy and paste new information over to what was previously displayed in the specified range, the values will be overwritten with the new info, which is fine, but the snippets from the previous display remains along with the new snippets. What can I include to ensure the prior information and the snippets get cleared and then paste the new set of information? Thank you.